# How can I accept unquoted strings containing backslashes?

Tags: bash, unix

I want a command to convert from windows to unix filenames, simply to replace backslashes with frontslashes... but without quoting the argument with "" because that's a chore when copy-pasting.

It works in the other direction (u2w) with the input quoted and without, but not for w2u.

```
machine:~/glebbb> w2u "a\b\c"

a/b/c

machine:~/glebbb> w2u a\b\c  

abc
```

How can I make it work? I tried every form of escaping, echo -E, printf etc, nothing seems to work!

```
function w2u {
    if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
        echo "w2u: must provide path to convert!"
        return 1
    else
        printf "\n%s\n\n" "$1" | sed -e 's#\\#\/#g'
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the usage of the function `w2u`, not in the implementation; the argument that the function will get will already have the backslashes removed as they'll be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: You should run `w2u 'a\b\c'`. You *must* use proper quoting. There's no way to have your cake and eat it.

Comment: Ah damn, you're right... the script doesn't get the proper values. The environment is windows so I guess there'll finally be a use for PowerShell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're copy-pasting and the path is contained in the X clipboard, you can use `xclip`:

```
xclip -o | sed -e 's#\\#\/#g'
```

If you've got a ton of file paths to convert, you can process the whole file instead:

```
sed ... < file
```

will produce a new stream with the backslashes changed to slashes.

Otherwise I can't think of any way how to not-escape the parameters to `w2u` and yet have backslashes lose their meaning.

Comment: I'm not on a *nix machine and don't have xclip but I guess "it can't be done in Bash" is technically correct, which is the best kind of correct, so I will accept it.

Comment: It might be worth specifying the platform the next time. Or, ideally, move to a UNIX derivative and enjoy the rest of it's fading glory while you still can.

Comment: Oh I imbibe, but not on a mandated work virtual machine... The real environment of the script is bsd bash over ssh, that's where these run, still no xclip :-\